# How to center text in second column to page - bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, alignment

I have a header with two columns. In the first column is the logo and in the second is a centered heading. Below that is the main content with a centered heading. I am trying to get it so that the heading in the header is centered to the main parent container like the heading in the main content is.
I'm using bootstrap 4.6.

Here is a drawing of what I am talking about:
[image]

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.row-color {
    background-color: #DCE6F2;
}
.logo-width img{
    width: 220px;
    height: 210px;
}
.column-width img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 115px;
}
#page-container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
footer {
    background-color: #024393;   
    color: #fff;             
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Title</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page-container" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row row-color align-items-center text-center p-5">
                <div class="col-2 logo-width text-center">                    
                    <img src="img/shelter_logo.svg" alt="Logo Here">                    
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="center">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>text</p>
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end row -->
            <div class="row my-5">
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-around">
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-auto">
                <div class="row justify-content-around p-3">
                    <div class="col text-center">                        
                        <h3>Heading</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <img src="#" alt="">                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <h3>Heading</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <img src="#" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <h3>Heading</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <img src="#g" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <h3>Heading</h3>                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>



        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/west4me/pen/vYywWVX

Comment: You should be using a new row for that column or else you can try CSS Grid.

Comment: If you change the second column in your header from `col` to `col-8`, then the content will center on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.col` will stretch to fill the row. In your case, you have a `.col-2` in your heading row, so the `.col` is equal to a `.col-10`.

If you want to center it, you need to be in the middle of the 12 columns bootstrap grid, which mean 2 cols on each side.

As Rick says, you need to replace your `.col` by a `.col-8`

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.row-color {
    background-color: #DCE6F2;
}
.logo-width img{
    width: 220px;
    height: 210px;
}
.column-width img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 115px;
}
#page-container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
footer {
    background-color: #024393;   
    color: #fff;             
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Title</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page-container" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row row-color align-items-center text-center p-5">
                <div class="col-2 logo-width text-center">                    
                    <img src="img/shelter_logo.svg" alt="Logo Here">                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="center">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>text</p>
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end row -->
            <div class="row my-5">
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-around">
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-auto">
                <div class="row justify-content-around p-3">
                    <div class="col text-center">                        
                        <h3>Heading</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <img src="#" alt="">                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <h3>Heading</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <img src="#" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <h3>Heading</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <img src="#g" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <h3>Heading</h3>                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>



        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, just couldn't get my head around it. Appreciate the help.